# how to calculate angle between two path lines on google map using lat-long coordinates

Tags: ios, google-maps, geolocation, gis, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to calculate angle between two path lines on Google map. I have the lat-long coordinates of the end points of the lines.
Please suggest If there is other information I can use to do this that is available from Google maps.

Comment: This is actually a pretty tricky problem with a lot of context-dependent information. However, if the lines are reasonably short and close to the equator and you don't need amazing accuracy, it's good enough to just treat the lat/long coordinates as Cartesian and compute the angle between them as you would on a flat surface. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System might be useful as well.

Comment: Oh, and for a bit more accuracy with the treat-it-as-Cartesian method, try multiplying the longitude deltas by the cosine of the latitude. (That still won't work near the poles though.)

Comment: You could also just convert the lat/long into x/y/z and treat it like a normal 3D vector that way, although that will be the angle through 3D space ("as the neutrino flies"), not the map-projected angle ("as the crow flies").

Comment: How to convert lat longs to x/y/z are there any formulas for this?

Comment: It's complicated. See the wiki article I linked to for the correct-ish approach (which is difficult), or you can just do it as a composition of two ordinary 3D rotations; start with a point at <0,0,1> and then rotate around the X axis by latitude, then around the Y axis by longitude.

Comment: How helpful will using bearing be? As I am going to use Google maps SDK for iOS and I guess it can calculate bearin between 2 points.. so when I want to calculate the angle between 2 lines I can calculate it as  (bearing of line 1 - bearing of line 2)

Comment: Bearing (as suggested in both full answers at the time) is also a reasonable way to do it. It really depends on what you're trying to determine; "angle between two lines" can mean a lot of different things when looking at the surface of an oblate spheroid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the distances are small you can use this method.
The accuracy reduces with large distances and the further you move from the equator.
First find bearings with [**computeHeading()**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical)

computeHeading(from:LatLng, to:LatLng)  .Returns the heading from one LatLng to another LatLng. Headings are expressed in degrees clockwise from North within the range [-180,180).

```
function getBearings(){
    var spherical = google.maps.geometry.spherical; 
    var point1 = markers[0].getPosition();// latlng of point1
    var point2 = markers[1].getPosition();
    var point3 = markers[2].getPosition();
    var bearing1 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(point1,point2);
    var bearing2 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(point2,point3);
    var angle =getDifference(bearing1, bearing2);
    return angle;
}
```

You can then use this function to calculate angle between the bearings.

```
function getDifference(a1, a2) {
    al = (a1>0) ? a1 : 360+a1;
    a2 = (a2>0) ? a2 : 360+a2;
    var angle = Math.abs(a1-a2)+180;
    if (angle > 180){
        angle = 360 - angle;
    }
   return   Math.abs(angle);
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me to understand formula for getDifference? Basically this 360/180 logic.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate both bearings using an API you have.
Then write a function angleDiff(angle1, angle2).

There are two possible angleDiff types: One that retunrs negative angles, too. 
And one that only delivers positive angles.

Test that function with these test cases:

angleDiff(350, 10): diff = 20
10, 350: diff = 20 (or -20)

170, 190 :diff = 20
190, 170: diff 20 (or -20)

0,360 and 360,0: diff = 0